# returning Viewable messes up path's so now js/css files don't load

Tags: java, jersey, filepath

I'm returning a `Viewable`in my java while which returns a `jsp`which is located in the `WebContent` directory. In that directory there are my `css`and `js`directories where my files are located. My `jsp`'s reference these files using relative paths. e.g `js/javascript.js`.

However, if I load any of these `.jsp`'s via a `return new Viewable("myPage.jsp");` in my `.java`files the paths seem to mess up as when the url is loaded the browser shows the url of the java file and all relative paths fail. How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The path you are using should be relative to the resources that return these, rather than to the JSP's themselves. Are these files accessible when you enter their URL's to the browser directly? If yes, then you just need to make sure you put the right path to the JSP files - e.g. use the absolute path instead of the relative one - like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css" />`